# How to handle exceptions in REST API

Tags: rest, go, exception

I want to build rest API end point to read log file and return its statistics.

```
172.31.8.70 - - [21/Mar/2021:00:00:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 -
172.31.17.28 - - [21/Mar/2021:00:01:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 -
172.31.45.113 - - [21/Mar/2021:00:01:14 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301
```

This is the sample behavior of my my log file. So I use regex to extract IP, date time and request type.

```
func IPStatistics(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    defer recoverInvalidAccess()
    var fn = "log_files/access_log"

    var res model.ResponseResult
    type IPData struct {
        Date        string `json:"date"`
        Time        string `json:"time"`
        RequestType string `json:"request_type"`
    }

    type Data struct {
        IPAddress string   `json:"ip_address"`
        IPData    []IPData `json:"ip_data"`
    }

    IPDataL1 := make(map[string][]map[string]string)

    file, err := os.Open(fn)
    if err != nil {
        res.Error = "error"
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // Start reading from the file with a reader.
    reader := bufio.NewReader(file)
    for {
        var buffer bytes.Buffer

        var l []byte
        var isPrefix bool
        for {
            l, isPrefix, err = reader.ReadLine()
            buffer.Write(l)
            // If we've reached the end of the line, stop reading.
            if !isPrefix {
                break
            }
            // If we're at the EOF, break.
            if err != nil {
                if err != io.EOF {
                    res.Error = "dfdfdf"
                }
                break
            }
        }
        line := buffer.String()
        ip := findIP(line)  // use find IP func 
        date := findDate(line)
        var time = date[len(date)-8:] // use find date func
        date = date[:len(date)-9]
        requestType := findRequstMethod(line)
        aMap := map[string]string{
            "requestType": requestType,
            "date":        date,
            "time":        time,
        }
        IPDataL1[ip] = append(IPDataL1[ip], aMap)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        fmt.Printf(" > > %s\n", IPDataL1) inside loop this prints array list
        
    }
    fmt.Printf(" > > %s\n", IPDataL1)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(IPDataL1) there is no any data in response
    return

}
```

while reading the file it prints `fmt.Printf(">> %s\n",IPDataL1)` inside the loop but at the end it prints exceptions and there is no response.

I use the above mentioned code to handle exceptions and also defer recoverInvalidAccess().

```
func recoverInvalidAccess() {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
        fmt.Println("Recovered", r)
    }
}
```

However, when I call  execute this via API call, each time it prints some errors from above code which is related to regex, and string slicing, etc.

Therefore, I think the error has not been handled in correct way. Can you please guide me to handle this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unless `findDate` guarantees to always return a string of *sufficient* length you should not be slicing the string carelessly, you should use `len` to determine whether or not you can actually slice it the way you want. The presented code also does not seem to me to warrant the use of `panic/recover` for error handling. Instead you should do proper error checking, proper bounds checking, proper `nil` checking, etc. then you don't have to worry about panics/exceptions and you can just handle normal error values, which is the more idiomatic approach.

Comment: Panic/recover should not be used like exception catching from other languages